# Configure Webmock to return the passed body hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest, webmock

Using Webmock, I'd like the stub to simply return the called body params. For example, I am calling the Mandrill API and passing an `options` hash.

I've tried this, but it is giving me an error:

```
@mandrill = stub_request(:any, "https://mandrillapp.com/api/1.0/").to_return(body: *)
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Solved!

```rb
module ApiStubs

  def stub_apis
    @mandrill = stub_request(:any, "https://mandrillapp.com/api/1.0/").to_return { |request| {body: request.body} }
  end

end
```